# Weird error in converting a numpy array to a tensor due to tensor id

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras-layer

I wrote a code to synthesize some face images and I have a custom layer which its task is to extract FaceNet embeddings so I can use these embeddings in addition to the images itself in my loss function but I get this error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: transpose expects a vector of size 0. But input(1) is a vector of size 4
     [[{{node training/Adam/gradients/conv2d/Conv2D_grad/Conv2DBackpropInput-2-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer}}]]
```

For simplicity, let's define my custom layer in a way that just return its input:

```
class my_layer(Layer):

  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(my_layer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  def call(self, x):
    y = tf.py_function(my_func,[x], Tout = tf.float32)
    y.set_shape((None, 160, 160, 3))
    return y

def my_func(x):
    y1 =x
    x = x.numpy()
    y2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=tf.float32)
    return y2
```

If I return y2 I get the same error but if I return y1, everything would be fine. It's really weird that if you return input tensor there's no error but if you convert it to a numpy array and then you convert it back to a tensor it throws me this error. I guess something will be missed when I convert the input tensor to an array. I checked the id of input tensor and created tensor y2. They were different. Maybe it is because of that but I don't know how to change the id of a tensor. But this seems really weird to me!

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, there must be something related to the id of tensor. So I edited my_func this way:

```
def my_func(x):
    y1 = x
    y2 = x
    x = x.numpy()
    y2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=tf.float32) + y2 - y1
    return y2
```

So, as we already set the id of y2 to the same of x so it worked. But if y2 modifies the shape of x, you can have tf.reducde_mean of (y2 - y1)! This is a very unusual way to keep the id of the output tensor but if you know how we can access to the tensor id, I would be so grateful. You can check your tensor id using print([y2]) for instance!